# Why does df -h show different information then fdisk -l

Tags: partitioning, fdisk, df

I am trying to understand the difference between the output of `fdisk -l` and `df -h`. As I understand, `fdisk` shows the partition size, and `df` shows the size of the filesystem.

My problem is that I have a mismatch between the size of the partition and the size of the filesystem.

from `fdisk -l`, we can see that the size of the partition mounted on `/dev/sda5/` is 797.2GiB.

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 894.3 GiB, 960197124096 bytes, 1875385008 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xab99345d

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048  197509119  197507072  94.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2        197511166 1875384319 1677873154 800.1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5        197511168 1869383679 1671872512 797.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       1869385728 1875384319    5998592   2.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 894.3 GiB, 960197124096 bytes, 1875385008 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

from `df` we can see that the size of the filesystem is 784GiB.

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  808K  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        93G   12G   76G  14% /
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda5       784G   70M  744G   1% /var/lib/test
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/900
```

I have total of 744G avialable space. This is ok because 5% of the filesystem (784) is reserved.

to summarize:

`fdisk -l`: 797.2G

`df -h`  : 784

**Where are the missing 13GiB?**

**edit**:

I used pxe preseed to create the partitions:

```
d-i partman/alignment select optimal
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                        \
     boot-root ::                                            \
             500 10000 1000000000 ext4                       \
                     $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                     method{ format } format{ }              \
                     use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                     mountpoint{ / }                         \
             .                                               \
             856000 1000 856000 ext4                         \
                     method{ format } format{ }              \
                     use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                     mountpoint{ /var/lib/test }             \
             .                                               \
             64 512 300% linux-swap                          \
                     method{ swap } format{ }                \
             .
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

I run `lsblk`. (

```
#lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 894.3G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0  94.2G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
├─sda5   8:5    0 797.2G  0 part /var/lib/test
└─sda6   8:6    0   2.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 894.3G  0 disk
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you resize this partition and if so, how?

Comment: @mook765, I used pxe. I edited my question.

Comment: `df -h` prints the human readable format, try simply `df` and you'll see the full number of bytes, you can compare this number between the two of them, also, add the output of `lsblk` so we can understand your drives geometry.

Comment: @Yaron Thanks, The same problem goes with `df`, there are still missing bytes.

Comment: Another answer I found: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336462/why-df-get-result-inconsistent-with-lsblk

Comment: Check  the real filesystem size with `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda5`, multiply `Block count` with `Block size` and see what the result is.

Answer (score 3):

You will always have a difference in the output of

```
~$ sudo fdisk -l
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda6       378750976 625139711 246388736 117.5G 83 Linux
```

and

```
~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       116G   61M  110G   1% /media/datam
```

In my case here I have a difference of about 1.5 GB which is about 1.3 % of the partition size.

To determine the real filesystem size you can use

```
~$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda6
Block count:              30798592
Block size:               4096
```

We can see that filesystem and partition have the same size here:

```
Filesystem size is  30798592 × 4096 = 126151032832 > 117.487304688 GiB
Partition size is  246388736 x  512 = 126151032832
```

From `man df`:

```
df displays the amount of disk space available on the file system
```

So `df` does not display the size of the filesystem, it displays the size
 which is available for the users. Some space in the filesystem is reserved for the
filesystem (e.g. Journal) and is not available for the users, thus not displayed.

When I calculate with 1.3% it will give about 10.4 GB difference for a 800 GB partition,
that's pretty near the amount of space you're missing, it's not lost in space, it's
filesystem-overhead.

Note: I stripped the command output in my examples to the relevant lines to keep it tidy.

**Space reserved for *root*:**

The reserved space for *root* is available, but only for the user *root*. `df` displays this amount of space as used, the confusing thing is, that `df` displays the same values wether you run `df` as *root* or as another user. In the default configuration 5% of space will be reserved for *root* (see for the reasons [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why)). It is possible to reduce this amount of space what I think makes sense for your pretty big partition, so more space will be available for other users. Feel free to reduce the space reserved for *root* to one or two percent with

```
sudo tune2fs -m X /dev/sda5
```

Replace `X` with the desired reserved-blocks-percentage. No need to unmount the partition, this can be done online. If you want to increase the reserved-blocks-percentage you should make sure that enough free space is left on the partition. The change will immediatly take effect.

Comment: First, thank you for your response. The thing that I do not understand, is that there is already a difference of 5% between the actual size and the available size in the output of `df`

Comment: @Kfir I added some infos regarding the 5% to the answer.